# Customize agenda view with no headers

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm trying to customize my agenda. My tasks have the following states: `NEXT`, `WAITING`, `TODO` and `DONE`. I want to customize my agenda view so that no header is shown. So far, I have:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("b" "Test"
     ;; commands
     ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-span 7)
              (org-deadline-warning-days 30)))
      (todo "NEXT" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "")))
      (todo "WAITING" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "")))
      (todo "TODO" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "")))))))
```

but in this way, an empty line is shown before each section.
Is there any way to get rid of the header at all?

Answer (score 1):

The space between agenda blocks is controlled by `org-agenda-block-seperator`.

> The separator between blocks in the agenda.
>   If this is a string, it will be used as the separator, with a newline added.
>   If it is a character, it will be repeated to fill the window width.
>   If nil the separator is disabled.  In ‘org-agenda-custom-commands’ this
>   addresses the separator between the current and the previous block.

Setting it to `nil` removes the separator entirely, leaving only `org-agenda-overriding-header` between the blocks, which you can also leave as `nil` instead of an empty string.

Comment: Tried it but the empty line is still there.

Comment: Does setting `org-agenda-compact-blocks` to `t` help?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I added the `(setq org-agenda-compact-blocks to t)` in the org config file... shall I add it in the custom command?